# Creating a VF page ‘Registration Form’ for Account object in Salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com

I have below requirement to Create a VF page – ‘Registration Form’ in Account Object having

1.Name field

2.Attachment area – where we can browse and add any document there

Expected UI-

[image]

Below is my VF code-

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="InputFileControllerExtension"> 
<apex:messages /> 
<apex:form id="theForm"> 
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" showHeader="true" title="Personal Details" >
            <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Name}" />
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockSection >
            <apex:inputFile value="{!attachment.body}" filename="{!attachment.name}"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Upload and save" action="{!save}"/> 
        </apex:pageBlockSection> 
        </apex:pageBlock> 
</apex:form>
```

Below is the APEX Class-

```
 public class InputFileControllerExtension
{
    private final Account acct;
    public Attachment attachment {get;set;}
    public PageReference save()
    {
        attachment.parentid = acct.id;
        insert attachment;
        return stdController.save();
    }
    public InputFileControllerExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController)
    { 
        attachment = new Attachment();
        this.acct = (Account)stdController.getRecord();
        this.stdController = stdController;
    } 
    ApexPages.StandardController stdController;
}
```

Error I am getting-

> Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Parent]: [Parent] Error is in expression '{!save}' in component in page file_upload_test: Class.InputFileControllerExtension.save: line 8, column 1

could you please help me to resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, your `account` doesn't exist yet. So the `id` is not populated yet. You didn't insert it.

But there's also a problem of communication between your visualforce page variable and your extension.

First, you have to make your `account` variable public, with a getter and a setter, to be accessed from your visualforce page:

```
public final Account acct {get; set;}
```

Then, you'll have to use this variable is your visualforce page to link your `inputfield` to the account name:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!acct.Name}" />
```

Finally, you have to insert the account before inserting the attachment:

```
    public PageReference save()
    {
        if(acct.Name != null){
           insert acct;    

           attachment.parentid = acct.id;
           insert attachment;
        }

        return null;
    }
```